# Renaming a database in cPanel

Tags: database, cpanel

Is there a way to rename database name in cPanel so the prefix with account name is dropped?

I tried to use Restore feature to upload a database from another server, but it added a suffix with account name, making it account_dbname. I just need it to be dbname.

Tried using MyPHP admin feature but it still keeps adding sufix when new name is given.

Thanks

Comment: if account name gets added automatically, it is to do with your host settings. You will have to open a support ticket as karan mavadhiya suggested below

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about MySQl database, go to phpmyadmin > select the database from the left sidebar , once inside the database, click operations >> Rename Databsase[image: Rename Database from Cpanel]

Answer (score 0):

**For cPanel:** If you want the same database user to have access to the renamed database, you should take note of the username already assigned to the database, which may or may not be similar to the name of the current database

1. In cPanel, click on MySQL Databases.
2. Scroll down to the Current Databases section of the page.
3. Find the database you are about to rename, and take note or remember the database user already assigned to the database.  You will need to know this for step 2.
4. You can return to the cPanel home screen to begin Step 1.

**Step 1:** Renaming the Database

1. From cPanel, click on phpMyAdmin. (It should open in a new tab.)
2. Click on the database you wish to rename in the left hand column.
3. Click on the Operations tab.
4. Where it says "Rename database to:" enter the new database name.
5. Click the Go button.
6. When it asks you to want to create the new database and drop the old database, click OK to proceed. (This is a good time to make sure you spelled the new name correctly.)
7. Once the operation is complete, click OK when asked if you want to reload the database.

**Step 2:** Reconfiguring User Permissions
If your hosting plan has cPanel, then you will need to reconfigure user permissions.

1. Go back to the main cPanel page.
2. Click on MySQL Databases.
3. Scroll down to the Add User To Database section of the page.
4. Select the database from the list (should be the new name).
5. Select the database user from the list (the same one that used to be associated with this database).
6. Click on Add button.
7. On the Manage User Privileges page that appears, check the box next to All Privileges.
8. Click on the Make Changes button.

**Step 3:** Update Scripts
You may need to update any scripts or applications that reference this database, since the name has changed, if you want them to continue to have access to this database.